# Scale many values by the same total scale iteratively

Tags: algorithms

This is a programming problem, but it's specifically math-based and the programmers I know aren't able to point me to the right solution.

Math has always been my worst subject.  I'm usually pretty good with the logical aspect of it, but getting specific numbers to do what I need can get impossible.

I've got a value, X, and values T ('to') and F('from').  There are also a multitude of unknown values ({Stars}) which have to scale with X.

Each time step (which varies), I need to multiply X and {Stars} by the same amount.  After (S) seconds, X should be equal to T.

By definition, X is F, and at the end of the operation, X is equal to (X * T/F) (which is equal to T).  For the sake of simplicity, it's impossible for X to ever equal or pass zero (so T and F are always the same sign).

Each time step, I need to do something like this, but I don't know how to calculate the ? value:

```
while ( time < S )
  mux = 1 + ? * timestep
  X = X * mux
  {Stars} = {Stars} * mux
// after the loop, X is guaranteed to be (initial X0 * F/T) (which is T)
// {Stars} contains unknown values which have scaled with X to become F/T * their original value
```

Comment: Alright, it appears that I've solved it.  There's still a hiccup at the endpoint, but I think that's due to some programming error I haven't tracked down yet.  The actual change in X appears to be correct.

First, the basic operation to get X from F to T - a simple slope equation (executed iteratively)

>X = X + timestep * slope, where slope = (T-F)/total time

But I need to use multiplication (since I need to multiply each value by the same amount to get them to scale together)

>X + timestep * slope = X * Z, where Z is the ? in my question

>1 + timestep * slope / currentX = Z

Comment: So the while loop becomes:    
  
    while ( time < S )  
      mux = 1 + timestep * slope / X  
      X = X * mux  
      {Stars} = {Stars} * mux

Comment: WELP that's unreadable xD  As soon as I can answer the question I'll move those to an answer.